# How to bidirectionally link X axis of HoloViews (hvplot) plot with panel DatetimePicker (or DatetimeRangePicker) widget

Tags: python, bokeh, panel, holoviews, hvplot

## Question:

I am struggling for a more than a week now to do something probably pretty simple:

1. I want to make a time series plot in which i can control the x axis
   range/zoom with a datetime picker widget.
2. I also want the datetime picker to be updated when the x range is
   changed with the plot zoom controls

So far I can do either but not both. It did work for other widgets such as the intslider etc.

*Requirements:*

- If the solution has 1 DatetimeRangePicker to define the x range or 2 DatetimePicker widgets (one for start one for end) would both work great for me.
- my datasets are huge so it would be great if it works with datashader

[image: Desired Result]

Any help is much appreciated :)

## What I tried:

**MRE & CODE BELOW**

1. Create a DatetimeRangePicker widget, plot the data using pvplot and set the `xlim=datatimerangepicker`.
   *Result*: the zoom changes with the selected dates on the widget, but zooming / panning the plot does not change the values of the widget.
2. Use  `hv.streams.RangeX` stream to capture changes in x range when panning / zooming. Use a pn.depends function to generate plot when changing DatetimeRangePicker widget.
   *Result*: the figure loads and zooming/panning changes the widget (but is very slow), but setting the widget causes `AttributeError`.
3. Create a DatetimePicker widget for start and end. Link them with `widget.jslink()` bidirectionally to x_range.start and x_range.end of the figure.
   *Result*: figure loads but nothing changes when changing values on the widget or panning/zooming.

## MRE & Failed Attempts

**Create Dataset**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.pandas

hv.extension('bokeh')

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)}, index=pd.date_range(start="2022", freq='D', periods=100))
```

**Failed Method 1:**
*plot changes with widget, but widget does not change with plot*

```
range_select = pn.widgets.DatetimeRangePicker(value=(df.index[0], df.index[-1]))
pn.Column(df.data.hvplot.line(datashade=True, xlim=range_select), range_select)
```

**Failed Method 2:**
*Slow and causes* `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'` *when changing widget*

```
range_select = pn.widgets.DatetimeRangePicker(value=(df.index[0], df.index[-1]))

@pn.depends(range_x=range_select.param.value)
def make_fig(range_x):
    fig = df.data.hvplot.line(datashade=True, xlim=range_x)
    pointer = hv.streams.RangeX(source=fig)
    tabl = hv.DynamicMap(show_x, streams=[pointer])  # plot useless table to make it work
    return fig + tabl

def show_x(x_range):
    if x_range is not None:
        range_select.value = tuple([pd.Timestamp(i).to_pydatetime() for i in x_range])
    return hv.Table({"start": [x_range[0]], "stop": [x_range[1]]}, ["start", "stop"]) if x_range else hv.Table({}) 

pn.Column(range_select, make_fig)
```

**Failed Method 3:**
*does not work with DatetimePicker widget, but does work other widgets (e.g. intslider)*

```
pn.widgets.DatetimePicker._source_transforms = ({})  # see https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/using-jslink-with-pn-widgets-datepicker/1116

# datetime range widgets
range_strt = pn.widgets.DatetimePicker()
range_end = pn.widgets.DatetimePicker()

# int sliders as example that some widgets work
int_start_widget = pn.widgets.IntSlider(start=0, step=int(1e6), end=int(1.7e12))
int_end_widget = pn.widgets.IntSlider(start=0, step=int(1e6), end=int(1.7e12))

points = df.data.hvplot.line(datashade=True)   # generate plot

# link widgets to plot:
int_start_widget.jslink(points, value="x_range.start", bidirectional=True)
int_end_widget.jslink(points, value="x_range.end", bidirectional=True)
range_strt.jslink(points, value="x_range.start", bidirectional=True)
range_end.jslink(points, value="x_range.end", bidirectional=True)

pn.Row(points,pn.Column( range_strt, range_end, int_start_widget, int_end_widget,))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```py
range_select = pn.widgets.DatetimeRangePicker(value=(df.index[0].to_pydatetime(), df.index[-1].to_pydatetime()))

curve = df.data.hvplot.line(datashade=True).apply.opts(xlim=range_select, framewise=True)

rxy = hv.streams.RangeX(source=curve)

def update_widget(event):
    new_dates = tuple([pd.Timestamp(i).to_pydatetime() for i in event.new])
    if new_dates != range_select.value:
        range_select.value = new_dates

rxy.param.watch(update_widget, 'x_range')

pn.Column(range_select, curve)
```

Basically we use `.apply.opts` to apply current widget value as the `xlim` dynamically (and set `framewise=True` so the plot ranges update dynamically). Then we instantiate a `RangeX` stream which we use to update the widget value. Annoyingly we have to do some datetime conversions because np.datetime64 and Timestamps aren't supported in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for this!! One small step I had to do to make it work was to replace your lambda function with the update_widget function to include a check if the values to update the widget were new other wise it caused an infinite loop. I edited your answer to include that (if approved) and accepted it. Thanks again!